# Align the facebook icon with the text in the button

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position, css-sprites

I have been trying **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/MmqK6/)** 
I couldn't get the output. Actually I want to center align the icon and the text inside the button.
Please help me to fix this
Here is my jsfiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/MmqK6/)**

Html code:

```
<p class="SecWrapper">
    <a href="" class="fbLogin fbBtn clearfix">
        <span style="margin:0 auto;">
            <i class="fbIcon spriteIcon"></i> 
            <i class="pull-left">Log In with Facebook</i>
        </span>
    </a>
</p>
```

Css code:

```
.SecWrapper{width:300px;}

.fbBtn,a.fbBtn{padding: 13px;
                background: #2a6496;
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                color: #fff;
                text-align:center;
                }

a.fbBtn:hover,.fbBtn:hover{color: #fff;}

.spriteIcon{float: left;
            background: url(http://i.imgur.com/egJconX.png) no-repeat;
            }

.fbIcon{background-position: -9px -65px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 25px;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Positioning here, assign `position: relative;` to your container element and `position` the *F* icon by using `position: absolute;` and `left` `top` properties

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MmqK6/3/)

```
.SecWrapper{
     width:300px;
     position: relative;
}

.fbIcon{
     background-position: -9px -65px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 70px; 
     top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to add (position: relative;) to this classname (.fbBtn)

Comment: I have added the changes you suggested See the page now http://i.imgur.com/CYBXp1T.png

Comment: @SureshPattu I just realized that you are using both the classes on same element, here's a fix for that, http://jsfiddle.net/MmqK6/3/